# Select non-missing values row-wise, from columns closest to a given column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R like this :

```
  country X2005 X2006 X2007 X2008 X2009 X2010
1  France    NA    NA    NA    23    NA    NA
2   Italy    NA    NA    12    NA    NA    NA
3   Spain    12    NA    14    NA    NA    NA
4 Belgium    NA    NA    12    NA    18    NA
```

I would like to create a new column without `NA` according to:
(1) If the "X2008" column has a non-`NA` value, select that value. (2) If the value of "X2008" is `NA`, take the value from the nearest column which contains a value.

For example for Italy it would be 12 and for Spain 14.
For Belgium, I do not care, we can take the biggest or the smallest.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's have a look at your data:

```
txt <- 'country X2005 X2006 X2007 X2008 X2009 X2010  
France NA NA NA 23 NA NA  
Italy NA NA 12 NA NA NA  
Spain 12 NA 14 NA NA NA  
Belgium NA NA 12 NA 18 NA'

df <- read.table(text = txt, header = T)

  country X2005 X2006 X2007 X2008 X2009 X2010
1  France    NA    NA    NA    23    NA    NA
2   Italy    NA    NA    12    NA    NA    NA
3   Spain    12    NA    14    NA    NA    NA
4 Belgium    NA    NA    12    NA    18    NA
```

These data are "wide", which can be tricky to work with. First we need to prepare the data. We'll reshape it to make it easier to work with, remove the missing values, and calculate how close each observation is to the year 2008:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
  gather(year, value, -country) %>% 
  mutate(year = as.numeric(gsub('X', '', year))) %>% 
  mutate(dist.from.2008 = abs(year - 2008)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value))

  country year value dist.from.2008
1   Spain 2005    12              3
2   Italy 2007    12              1
3   Spain 2007    14              1
4 Belgium 2007    12              1
5  France 2008    23              0
6 Belgium 2009    18              1
```

Finally, for each country, we keep the single year that has a value that is closest to 2008:

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  filter(dist.from.2008 == min(dist.from.2008)) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == min(row_number()))

  country  year value dist.from.2008
  <fct>   <dbl> <int>          <dbl>
1 Italy    2007    12              1
2 Spain    2007    14              1
3 Belgium  2007    12              1
4 France   2008    23              0
```

Comment: Nice answer, but re-writing df over df is never a good idea. I would assign  a different name to it

Comment: True. But for demonstration purposes I simply broke up what could have been one continuous dplyr chain.

Comment: Fantastic, it's really great.  
Thank you very much for this answer, I would never have succeeded alone.  
Thank you